# Given $f$ is strictly increasing, is $f$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f \in C^1(\Bbb{R})$ such that $f'(x)>0$ always with $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)=0$, then is $f$ bounded above?

Tried many functions but couldn't find any counter, all seems to be satisfying, not sure if the statement is true or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, consider,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x-1 & x\leq 1,\\ \log x & x>1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: this is not in $C^1$

Comment: Yes it is, it is continuous with continuous derivative, this is what you are meaning by $C^1$, correct?

Comment: @Goal123 Now it should be $C^1$, you have $f'(x) = 1/x$ if $x>1$ and $f'(x) = 1$ if $x\le1$.

Comment: Yes right, now it seems to be working

Answer (score 3):

Here's a counterexample with no need to split into cases:
$$
f(x) = \ln(\ln(1+e^x))
.
$$

Answer (score -2):

Try $\tanh(x)$, it fullfills all of your assumptions.

\edit
This is a copunterexample:
$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for $x\ge1$ and $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ for $x\le 1$

Comment: This does not answer the question, you must either prove that the statement is true or provide a counterexample. This is just an example that there is a bounded function satisfying the assumptions but does not say that all functions which satisfy the assumptions are bounded.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I missunderstood the question.